# subseting in R with for-loop

Tags: r

I'm facing some troubles trying to subset data with some criteria. Please, if I could get some help would be wonderful.
Here is my problem....

I have a data frame with variables from X1 to X9. Data stored in this variables are double. I need a for-loop to look through this variables and return the lines that meet the criteria....let's say:

look through the variables from X1 to X9 and
return data where (X1,X2,X3)==(5.2,6.3,7.1) for instance.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Sorry, I did not make my self very clear.
As I have variables from X1 to X9 and the values there I'm filtering can occur in any variable, I can find the rows with the code bellow.

But I wouldn't like to perform this task manually replacing any variable combination to extract. That's why I thougth in a for loop to do this but couldn't acomplish. Thanks.

`vars <- c("X1", "X2","X3") cond <- c(5.2,6.3, 7.1) databas %>% filter( .data[[vars[[1]]]] == cond[[1]], .data[[vars[[2]]]] == cond[[2]], .data[[vars[[3]]]] == cond[[3]] )`

Comment: Hey Marco, would you be able to edit your comment to include a sample of data for us to work with?  You can use the `head()` and `dput()` functions to print out something we could copy and paste in our consoles.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to transpose your columns first so that your dataframe is long instead of wide. You can do this by using the tidyr::gather function. After that you can filter your dataframe. You dont necessarily need a loop.

```
df_filtered <- tidyr::gather(your_df, value = Value, key = ColumnNames, 
               dplyr::starts_with('X')) %>%
               dplyr::filter( ColumnNames == "X1" & Value == 5.2 |
                              ColumnNames == "X2" & Value == 6.3 |
                              ColumnNames == "X3" & Value == 7.1 )
```

Comment: If you have a newer version of tidyr you can also use the `pivot_longer()` function.